# Session Inconsistency Between Requests in Flask-Redis App Deployed on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, flask, session, heroku, redis

I have a React frontend that interacts with a Flask backend, which uses Redis for session management. My application works as expected locally, but when deployed on Heroku, I encounter an issue where a new session is created for each request, specifically between the `start_game` and `make_choice` endpoints. This results in session inconsistency, as the `make_choice` request does not recognize the session created by `start_game`. Can you please help me?

## Flask Config

```
app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='None',
    SESSION_TYPE='redis',
    SESSION_PERMANENT=True,
    SESSION_USE_SIGNER=True,
    SESSION_REDIS=Redis.from_url(os.getenv('REDISCLOUD_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379'))
)
Session(app)
```

## CORS Config

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=["http://localhost:3000", "https://myapp.herokuapp.com"])
```